# Any reason not to throw an ArgumentException in a powershell param() block?

Tags: powershell

I was looking for a way to make required parameters in powershell when I discovered [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/12/14/powershell-script---marking-a-parameter-as-required.aspx) suggesting I do the following:

```
param(
    [string] $ObjectName = $(Throw "Parameter -ObjectName must be set to the name of a database object")
);
```

After digesting for a while I came to the conclusion that it might be better to throw an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) as opposed to a string:

```
param(
    [string] $ObjectName = $(Throw New-Object System.ArgumentException "Parameter -ObjectName must be set to the name of a database object","ObjectNamt")
);
```

Now from a C# point of view the latter would be better. Is there any reason this practice does not translate in powershell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PowerShell 2.0 you can mark the parameter as Mandatory and let PowerShell do the work for you:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        Position=0,
        HelpMessage='ObjectName must be set to the name of a database object')]
    [string]
    $ObjectName
)
```

Comment: Apparently thats new in Powershell 2.0, just found this: http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2009/01/parameter-attributes-in-powershell-v2.html. Its hard to find good powershell documentation.

Comment: Check this help topic: about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters.

Comment: I would add a [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] to that.  You could also add a [ValidateSet()] if you new all the possible options.

Comment: Mandatory parameters would not accept empty or null values, it will keep prompting you for a value.

Comment: As Shay mentions, there is no way to suppress the prompt on Mandatory parameters, making them not so useful in headless scenarios.

Comment: @MartinSuchanek: In a headless scenario you would call the function while supplying the required parameters. :)
The prompt just makes it easier if you do it wrong on an interactive console.